# Discord.py: Is using cogs a waste of time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

If I want to split my code into multiple files, I can just write bash script like this:

```
cat first.py second.py third.py > run.py
python ./run.py
```

On the other hand, I have to add quite a bit of codes in order to use cogs.
Is there a reason/advantage to use cogs despite of this overhead?

Comment: this code doesn't split but join code into one file. But why to do this if in python you could use `from first import *`, `from second import *`, `from third import *` and still keep it in separated files.

Comment: No it doesn't work. Since `bot = commands.Bot()` stuffs are in one file, functions in other files doesn't know what 'bot' is, and error occurs while importing. That's why I used cat instead of using `from ~ import *`. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: maybe you should execute functions with bot - `function(bot)` If you want better help then create better question - with all needed information. We can't read in your mind.

Comment: btw: if you don't like `cogs` then simply don't use it.

Comment: I do want to split files, and yes, I'm doing just fine with my 'cat' bash script. But I was just curious about advantages of using cogs

Comment: I see one advance - you keep code in separated file so you don't have to watch it any more and you can work with smaller code at screen. You can also reuse it in other project without copy all to new file. if you would work in team then someone else could work on Cog and you would use newer version without copy code back to your file.

Comment: My bash script already does that, too. **I run the bash script instead of .py file each time I want to launch the bot.** I can work on smaller code, someone else can work on other smaller codes, and it'll all come together when I run the bash script. I was asking for advantage over my method. Also never mind, someone actually gave me a helpful answer. Btw, 'Simply don't use it' - please don't say that to other questioners. Anyone can come up with that answer, and it doesn't help at all. I wasn't complaining about `cogs` man. Just curiosity.

Comment: There is many persons which try to use something which they don't need it because then thing they have to use it - and `'Simply don't use it'` is very useful for them.

Comment: BTW: here is place for comments, and answers are below - and I also gave you only my comment, not answer for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few reasons why I prefer to use cogs for my `discord.py` bot, even when they only perform a few functions.

1. **Object-Oriented Programming**: I don't know how much I can elaborate here. OOP makes code so much easier to read and maintain. Now, you could definitely still use OOP without cogs, but using them makes it a whole lot easier. After all, the main point of cogs is to allow a programmer to use OOP instead of functional programming, and it says just that at the top of the Cogs documentation.

> There comes a point in your bot’s development when you want to organize a collection of commands, listeners, and some state into one class. Cogs allow you to do just that.

2. **Activating and Deactivating Specific Features**: If your bot is added to multiple guilds, there is a good chance that the guild owners will want to customize which features are actually used in their guild.
3. **Isolating Issues**: In my personal experience, using cogs has made debugging my code so much easier. I just comment out the `add_cog` statements until I can narrow down which contains the bug. I guess this is part of point (1), but I count it as an additional perk.

I definitely am biased towards cogs since I have been using them so much lately. I would add more items to my list (and I might continue to edit it in the future), but these are the easiest I could think of. As far as I know, cogs don't add any extra functionality to your code, but it does organize it much better. And hey, point -1, you get the cool categories when using the default *help* command!

Comment: I didn't know using cogs adds categories to default help command!
Dynamically loading/unloading features sounds cool too.

Comment: Honestly, even though cogs don’t do a ton, they are pretty cool.

Comment: One more thing, in between point 2. and 3.: cogs allow you to reload parts of your codebase without having to disconnect/reconnect the whole bot from the web API.
I'll add that as cogs are in fact Python modules, it's pretty good for logging too (eg. instanciating a logger instance per cog).
And of course, they also increase reusability.

Comment: @JacobLee sure, go ahead. Maybe one should point out that generally, modularity is a good thing in software engineering.